# Flip 0 and 1 bits in pandas DataFrame efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had an issue switching a binary variable in-place for a large DF... this ended up working; posting in case this is an issue for another user.

```
dfSet2['TargetDefault'] = dfSet2.apply(
    lambda x: (0 if x['TargetDefault']==1 else 1), axis=1)
```

Is there a faster/easier way to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfkxG.png)

Comment: please edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I got it right, you have them as `0` and `1` and want to swap them?

```
df['coli'] = (~df.coli.astype(bool)).astype(int)
```

Comment: ...they were 0=bad, 1=good. Had to run a check on 0=good, 1=bad. Also learning, and b/t r and python, it's hard to recall when and where to use what. Your sol = 3ms v lambda = 3000ms. Awesome. Thanks for a much quicker execution.

Comment: @GeoffNel The general rule is to avoid `apply` as much as you can, it's very slow. Pandas takes time to master. Also if this worked for you please consider accepting it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as

```
dfSet2['TargetDefault'] = 1 - dfSet2['TargetDefault']
```